# AWS EC2 php files

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I noticed my php files, when transferred to EC2, don't work unless the have the "php" in the opening `<? php...?>`

A lot of my files were written without it as `<? ...?>`

Is there an easy setting to allow the way I've written them, or will I have to go change all?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable PHP's shortened open tags in PHP.INI by setting `short_open_tag` to `1`. Presumably this had been done on your development system

However, this is discouraged in the PHP reference which you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

You alternative is to change everything to `<?php...`